# How to redirect from an Yesod subsite to master (caller) site without hardcoding master routes in subsite?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a simple scenario of creating a new persistent entity in an Yesod subsite. After posting and inserting a new entity, the subsite should redirect to the caller site (the master site). The master site may be a subsite itself.

How can I redirect to the caller site from the subsite?

Below is a code snippet of my attempt:

```
instance
  ( Yesod m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , RenderMessage m FormMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => YesodSubDispatch CntrCrud m where
  yesodSubDispatch = $(mkYesodSubDispatch resourcesCntrCrud)

postCntrNewR ::
  ( Yesod m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , RenderMessage m FormMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => SubHandlerFor CntrCrud m Html
postCntrNewR = liftHandler $ do
  ((r,w),e) <- runFormPost $ cntrForm Nothing
  case r of
    FormSuccess x -> do
      _ <- runDB $ insert x
      redirect ???toMaster???
    _ -> defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewCountry}
  <form method=post enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    ^{w}
    <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
      _{MsgSave}
    <a href=@{???toMaster???} .btn.btn-secondary role=button>
      _{MsgCancel}
|]

cntrForm :: (Yesod m, RenderMessage m AppMessage, RenderMessage m FormMessage)
  => Maybe Cntr -> Html -> MForm (HandlerFor m) (FormResult Cntr, WidgetFor m ())
cntrForm mx extra = do
.....
```

Where `???toMaster???` is a placeholder. Thanks.

I tried to use `getRouteToParent` as in the following code snippet, but `getRouteToParent` returns the route (full path) to  the same subsite:

```
postCntrNewR ::
  ( Yesod m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , RenderMessage m FormMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => SubHandlerFor CntrCrud m Html
postCntrNewR = do
  tp <- getRouteToParent
  liftHandler $ do
    ((r,w),e) <- runFormPost $ cntrForm Nothing
    case r of
      FormSuccess x -> do
        _ <- runDB $ insert x
        redirect $ tp CntrNewR
      _ -> defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewCountry}
  <form method=post action=@{tp CntrNewR} enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    ^{w}
    <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
      _{MsgSave}
    <a href=@{tp CntrNewR} .btn.btn-secondary role=button>
      _{MsgCancel}
|]
```

Above, `redirect $ tp CntrNewR` and `@{tp CntrNewR}` redirects and links to the same subsite where they are called an not to the master site. (`CntrNewR` is a route defined in the subsite). As such, the `<form method=post action=@{tp CntrNewR}...` works correctly, posting to the same subsite, but it is not what I expect for redirecting to the master site.
Thanks.

Comment: `getRouteToParent` from `Yesod.Core.Handler`?

Comment: I surely tried ```getRouteToParent```, but for some reason, ```getRouteToParent``` returns the same route (full path) to the same subsite. Please, see the code snippet I added above. Maybe I should use ```getRouteToParent``` in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to let the master site to provide the route:

```
-- src/Dictionary/Cntr/Data.hs
...
data CntrCrud = CntrCrud

class (Yesod m, RenderMessage m FormMessage) => YesodCntr m where
  toMaster :: m -> Route m

mkYesodSubData "CntrCrud" [parseRoutes|
/ CntrNewR GET POST
|]
...
```

```
-- src/Foundation.hs
...
instance YesodCntr App where
  toMaster _ = CntrsR
...
```

```
-- src/Dictionary/Cntr/CntrSub.hs
...
instance
  ( YesodCntr m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => YesodSubDispatch CntrCrud m where
  yesodSubDispatch = $(mkYesodSubDispatch resourcesCntrCrud)

postCntrNewR ::
  ( YesodCntr m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  , YesodPersist m
  , YesodPersistBackend m ~ SqlBackend
  ) => SubHandlerFor CntrCrud m Html
postCntrNewR = do
  tp <- getRouteToParent
  master <- getYesod
  liftHandler $ do
    ((r,w),e) <- runFormPost $ cntrForm Nothing
    case r of
      FormSuccess x ->  do
        _ <- runDB $ insert x
        redirect $ toMaster master
      _ -> defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewCountry}
  <form method=post action=@{tp CntrNewR} enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    ^{w}
    <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
      _{MsgSave}
    <a href=@{toMaster master} .btn.btn-secondary role=button>
      _{MsgCancel}
|]
      
getCntrNewR ::
  ( YesodCntr m
  , RenderMessage m AppMessage
  ) => SubHandlerFor CntrCrud m Html
getCntrNewR = do  
  tp <- getRouteToParent
  master <- getYesod
  liftHandler $ do
    (w,e) <- generateFormPost $ cntrForm Nothing
    defaultLayout [whamlet|
<fieldset .border.p-2>
  <legend>_{MsgNewCountry}
  <form method=post action=@{tp CntrNewR} enctype=#{e} novalidate .needs-validation>
    ^{w}
    <button type=submit .btn.btn-primary>
      _{MsgSave}
    <a href=@{toMaster master} .btn.btn-secondary role=button>
      _{MsgCancel}
|]
      
cntrForm :: (Yesod m, RenderMessage m AppMessage, RenderMessage m FormMessage)
  => Maybe Cntr -> Html -> MForm (HandlerFor m) (FormResult Cntr, WidgetFor m ())
cntrForm mx extra = do
...
```